# Rails Assets: Cleaning Up Assets [CSS/JS Files]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I didn't find anything here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html about cleaning up the public/assets directory

I have tons of stylesheets/js files precompiled under public/assets

How to clean them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean using the following command:

```
rake assets:clean
```

or you can safely delete directories inside `public/assets` directory.

Comment: Thanks! I can see now that files that start with application- are removed. (marked as deleted in textmate) but what about the other stuff?

Comment: @Newbie, please explain what other stuffs are?

Comment: For example js files related to deleted controllers overview-5c421d0e8106ca348c51d05cfe814ca5.js or multiple files of same controller pods-6f77bf6debdcef062a9c45d507a5ec1f.js and pods-624efafb400042b973d79e3720101ccd.js

Comment: Can I just delete them myself? and then run bundle exec rake assets:precompile again?

Comment: `rake assets:clean` should have deleted them because basically what that task does is run `rm -rf path_to_public/assets`.  But yes you can remove them yourself and they will be regenerated when you run `rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: Yeah I don't know! It only deleted 4 files! Thanks